# SQL, Get counts for each date with slight twist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have order, and ordereditemline where ordereditemline is each line(product) in the order.

Each line (product) has an associated date.  (You can think of a ticket product which has a specified date)

I've simplified the tables as below.

```
create table order  (
 id integer NOT NULL,
)


CREATE TABLE order_ordereditemline (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    order_id integer NOT NULL,
    date_at date,
    );
```

For a given date range, I'd like to get order count for each date.
([8/11: 3, 8/12: 0, 8/13: 4 ...])

`8/11: 3` means there is 3 orders which has at least a line with date_at 8/11.

It is possible that for a total of 100 orders in a date range, sum of counts for each date could exceed 100.

Not sure if this is possible with sql..
I'm using postgres, if it matters.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY, combined with COUNT(*).

Comment: I thought group by, partitions into disjoint sets. but I need some of orders counted multiple times.

Comment: Do you need to display a date if there are no order lines on that date but it is in the range of dates you have specified?

Comment: @chillysapien would be plus but not required. I could do it after the query.

Answer (score 1):

you can use count and group by  based  on joined  tables

```
select t1.id, date(t2.date_at), count(*)
from order
inner join order_ordereditemline t2  on t1.id = t2.order_id
group by  t1.id, date(t2.date_at)
date(t2.date_at)
```

and if you need  the value aggregated for date only  you can

```
select date(t2.date_at), count(*)
from order
inner join order_ordereditemline t2  on t1.id = t2.order_id
group by date(t2.date_at)
order by date(t2.date_at)
```

Comment: Doesn't the count display counts for each (order / date_at) ? instead of each date_at?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`generate_series()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) to calculate *zeros* for dates, when you have no data at all:

```
select    date '2016-08-11' + d, count(distinct order_id)
from      generate_series(0, date '2016-08-14' - date '2016-08-11') d
left join order_ordereditemline on date_at = date '2016-08-11' + d
group by  1
```

Or, in prepared statement friendly format:

```
select    :start_date + d, count(distinct order_id)
from      generate_series(0, :end_date - :start_date) d
left join order_ordereditemline on date_at = :start_date + d
group by  1
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not try the following, but do you think it could help you (may be I didn't understand your question)? (it uses just one table):

```
SELECT DATE_AT, COUNT(*) AS NUM_ORD_DAT
    (SELECT ID, DATE_AT
    FROM ORDER_ORDEREDITEMLINE
    GROUP BY ID, DATE_AT
    ) A
GROUP BY DATE_AT
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought my question was clear but I guess it was not.

Following is the answer I came up with, although I'm not sure if its best or not-stupid answer.

```
select date(t3.date_at), count(*)
from (
    select t1.id, date(t2.date_at) as date_at, count(*)
    from o t1
        inner join line t2 on t1.id = t2.order_id
    group by t1.id, date(t2.date_at)) t3
group by date(t3.date_at);
```